# Как в angular7 передать значение фильтров в url?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Как в angular7 передать значение фильтров в url?
Все фильтруется в angular, но сейчас понадобилось передавать значение фильтров в url (к примеру, если я хочу поделиться ссылкой на отфильтрованный товар)

Comment: а как вы фильтруете?

Comment: `queryParams` используйте и будет вам счастье

Comment: @Komdosh больше информации https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955728/angular-routes-query-parameters